# Reduce the number of queries needed by hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

When populating a table from a database using hibernate, one would ideally want to use the least amount of queries so their application is quick. Ideally you would not want to do more queries than there are columns in the table you are constructing, as a group by query would allow you to populate all the rows. So if you had m columns, and n rows, you would only want to perform m queries.

However I find it hard to achieve this within my Daos without writing new methods. Let's say you were dealing with an Entity called Employee, and you wanted to calculate average number of hours worked, you would then need 2 methods:

```
public interface EmployeesDao
{
    public List<Double> averageOfHoursWorked(List<Integer> ids);
    public double averageOfHoursWorked(Integer id);
}
```

So when you want to create a table, you would use the method accepting a list, but when you are just dealing with a single employee you would use the one which takes a single ID.

But I don't want to write 2 methods, I just want to write one ideally. But if I write one method, I end up using a for loop which makes a whole bunch of queries instead of just one:

```
    // THIS IS BAD, creates many queries
    List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(1,3,5,99, 1921);
    for (Integer id : ids) {
        double avg = dao.averageOfHoursWorked(id);
        // .... doing some table stuff with avg...
    }

    // THIS IS GOOD, only 1 query, yet now I must write more code ):
    List<Double> avgs = dao.averageOfHoursWorked(ids);
    for (Double avg : avgs) {
        // .... doing some table stuff with avg...
    }
```

So I know the second version is much quicker, but it takes me longer to code then. But as I was writing this I figured I could do something like this:

```
class EmployeesDaoImp implements EmployeesDao {

    @Override
    public double averageOfHoursWorked(Integer id) {
        return averageOfHoursWorked(Arrays.asList(id)).get(0);
    }
}
```

Then I would just have to write `List<Double> averageOfHoursWorked(List<Integer> ids)`, is this a good idea? Does someone have a more elegant way of making tables in general with hibernate? Maybe a builder pattern or something would be nicer like:

`Table table = dao.buildTable().withIds(ids).columnId().columnAvgHoursWorked().columnDaysOff()`

where columnId() would give you a column of ids, columnAvgHoursWorked, would give you another column with the hours worked and so on. What is the most optimal way of making tables with hibernate, requiring the least amount of queries and code.

Comment: I get the general gist of what you're asking but it's still kind of unclear. Can you give a (possibly simplified) version of your database schema and how it translates to the mxn tables you are making? Can you also show a snippet of the code you are using to create the table? Note, though, that in general, you can write custom queries with HQL, so there is always the option of creating your own specific queries in a dbms-independent way. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql as a start.

Comment: I think I will delete this question, I can't think of a way to phrase it without being more clear and not too broad, I just want to minimize the amount of code I am writing yet not perform too many database operations.

Comment: I cannot delete this question, can a moderator please close this, or just vote close on my question please.

Comment: Ivan Sotello's answers are not helping this either lol. I regret this question like a hangover haha.

Comment: It's a reasonable question. Just needs some more specifics. I wouldn't worry about it. It'll meet its natural fate sooner or later, be it receiving a decent answer, being deleted, or just being forgotten.

Comment: Ha ok I will try again to refactor, probably just going to get super low quality answers.

Comment: @JasonC please review question now thanks.

Comment: Well you can probably hack something by using an [`InExpression`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/InExpression.html) with the ID and a list of IDs but this really isn't what you should be doing, it will only cost performance elsewhere. The correct approach to this is to [properly configure Hibernate caching](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm) to avoid multiple queries per object, and to completely ignore db performance optimizations in your code unless you've actually profiled it and identified that's where a problem is.

Comment: Yeah it is a problem, some of the queries are a bit intense.

Comment: (Note that the second-level cache is likely what you are interested in here, presuming you have short-lived Hibernate sessions).

Comment: The caching sounds good but I'm typically in the Controller of Spring App, and calling methods which are creating and closing transactions, so I don't know how helpful the caching really is in that situation, will I still get the caching benefits?

Comment: Another strategy you could take depends on how you are determining the list of employee IDs to query. For example, if you're interested in retrieving the average number of hours worked of all employees between the age of 30 and 40, you might retrieve said list of employees in a single query with e.g. `session.createCriteria(Employee.class).add(Restrictions.between("age", 30, 40)).list()`. Then you have all the employees of interest, from just a single query. I'm assuming your ID lists aren't completely random.

Comment: You will likely get the caching benefits. Read through the caching docs and take a look at the providers to see which ones might work for you, then configure, check performance, tweak accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Btw you also may want to tweak your connection pooling strategies. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc (or for whatever version of hibernate you're using) for a bit more info; the default Hibernate strategy isn't the greatest. C3P0 is pretty widely used and has much better performance in high load (many client) environments. Won't help query performance but will reduce overhead in high traffic applications, dunno if that applies. But check built-in too; you don't want to be reconnecting for every session.

Comment: Oh and last comment: *"Then I would just have to write List<Double> averageOfHoursWorked(List<Integer> ids), is this a good idea?"* Yes that is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Answer (score -1):

At first, sorry for my poor english.
I think that is possible to create one DTO object that will be the data object and will contain all informations to be used in your JSP, you will put these object as return of one unique method and in one unique call solve your problem.

for example:

`public List getAllEmployeesWithAverageHoursWorked(int start, int finish){`

```
List<EmployeeDTO> result = new ArrayList<EmployeeDTO>();
///execute query that load registers that start in parameter start and finishes in parameter finish

return result;
```

}

The class EmployeeDTO will have all fields that you will need to use in your JSP page, or, if this option don't solve this question, you will change the method and the class EmployeeDTO to have the fields that you need.

Comment: The question is asking how I avoid doing your very answer. I don't want to have to write a custom dao method every time I make a table. I just want to reuse what I have. But I also don't want to then make 100 database calls if I don't need to. But when I reuse what I have, it ends up doing that.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understanda very weel your question, but i will give three forms, and i think that one can help.

1 - use generics and use the same DAO for all types of objects that you have in your software.

2 -  in my answer is possible to specify the start and finish points that you needs to read, for example: you readed 10 records, and now needs to read more than, then you pass 10 and 20, and read more 10.

3 - in the first call you will put the records that you need in a static variable and use (it's horrible).

If your problem is not "write" code, use generics, it is very good to solve this problem.

But, if i my answer isn't correct, please write your question again, but with other words, to i can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that now i understand your problem, see the following option:

```
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T>{

       private Class<T> entityBeanType;

       @Autowired
       protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

       public GenericDAOImpl() {

          ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
           Type type = genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) type;

           this.entityBeanType = clazz;
       }

       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       public T save(T t) {
            T t1 = (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(t);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
           return t1;
       }
    }

</code>
```

Repair that if you need to create another table, you will can extend this class to create a concrete DAO.

Example:

1 - create a table User and use the following code:

```
public class UserDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<User> implements UserDAO{
    ///other specific methods will be here
}
```

2 - create a table Receipts and use the following code:

```
public class ReceiptsDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Receipts> implements     ReceiptsDAO{
  ///other specific methods will be here
}
```

The generic type T can be some entity of your software.

I hope that my answer can help you.

Comment: Please stop posting many answers, format your answers, try to just have 1 answer if you can. You are filling this post with crap.